# Why ssh uses .ssh/id_rsa as a pubkeyauthentication?

Tags: ssh, authentication, rsa

When trying to ssh -v 'somehost'

```
Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

And why he telling that it's type 1 instead of type 2

```
debug1: identity file /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kaldown/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1_hpn13v11 FreeBSD-20140420
```

in sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin no
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
```

P.S. I'm using FreeBSD 10.1 which have a problems with ssh-copy-id, telling strange

```
Unmatched '
```

So I just scp my public key in .ssh/authorized_keys of exact user

1) Why it uses .ssh/id_rsa instead of .ssh/id_rsa.pub as a public key?

2) Why it's telling me that type 1, when I created this with ssh -t rsa (rsa2) key

3) Why I can't connect with keys, but password only with that config.

Server-side: CentOS 7, 3.10

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
restorecon -r -vv /home/user/.ssh
```

Will fix problem.

Found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1932058)

Comment: Ubuntu does not have restorecon installed

Answer (score 1):

Your `id_rsa` file contains information about both your private and public key. It is only offering the public part of the key.

I believe that type 1 or type 2 designates whether it is an RSA or DSA key.

Answer (score 1):

sshd_config is for the server so that's where you are saying look in this file for the public key to make sure it matches a private key your client is sending.

Public keys on server go in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Then the client sends its private key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa and the server matches them up and allows you in

The client side is setup here

```
[root@chef01-east.domain.com /etc/ssh]# grep IdentityFile /etc/ssh/ssh_config
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

The comments also mean they are defaults for the client.

If you want to send a different key you can always do

```
ssh -i /path/to/key/file user@host.com
```

Comment: 1) ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on server => ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of account which I trying to authenticate? So I copied my id_rsa.pub to that direction. 2) I tried to send both: id_rsa and id_rsa.pub by specifying ssh -i option. Still can't login by keys, but after commenting '#PasswordAuthentication no' I can reach server with password-only. Sorry, may be I didn't understand what you trying to tell me either.

Comment: But thank's for make it clear with understanding that client should sent exact private key to server for matching.

Comment: if everything is setup right it's usually permissions on the server side ~/.ssh needs to be owned by the user and 700 and authorized_keys needs to be 600

Comment: Yes it is: <code>ls -la .ssh/
total 4
drwx------. 2 forcookies wheel  28 Dec  9 18:03 .
drwx------. 3 forcookies wheel  60 Dec  9 04:51 ..
-rw-------. 1 forcookies wheel 381 Dec  9 18:03 authorized_keys
</code>

Comment: =| No, no, no. Its **never** ever okay for anything in a PKI system to send a _private_ key unless both parties own it and are extremely confident in the privacy of the channel they use. _Private_ means always private. What the SSH client would be sending is the _public_ key related to the private key. The _public_ key is then used by the server to encrypt things that can only be decrypted by the corresponding _private_ key. The client would already have the server's _public_ key so it could encrypt stuff to send to the server as well.